# Can I restrict different portions of a Sharepoint page to different users?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a couple different Sharepoint pages (Sharepoint Word docs) all with roughly the same purpose and information, but for management reasons, some of it needs to be restricted from a certain set of users. We keep having to update each page in several different places any time a single change or update is made.

It'd be easier to be able to mark certain tables on a single page with specific permissions. Is that something Sharepoint can even do, though?

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have an enterprise license for on-premise the best way to achieve this is by using targeted audience feature on the webparts.

Answer (score 0):

You could check SecurityTrimmedControl, you could hide the content based on user permission.

https://rijsat.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/security-trimmed-control-in-sharepoint-2013/